# Websockets library returns error 1011 but the version I'm using doesn't have docs for that error

Tags: python, websocket

I'm using the [websockets](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/) Python library to implement an asynchronous socket server for my program. Because the client end of this program doesn't run constantly (it connects to the server, uploads some data and then disconnects), I was getting the following error:

```
websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: WebSocket connection is closed: code = 1011 (unexpected error), no reason
```

Now I did some googling and according to [the docs](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#websockets.protocol.WebSocketCommonProtocol) error 1011 is caused when the server sends a ping to the client, doesn't receive a pong and errors out (which causes problems with my program as the client isn't constantly connected to the server). You can get around this by setting `ping_timeout` to `None`, although when I did this more errors were thrown.

So I did some more digging and I found that because I've been using discord.py in my program (which itself uses websockets), I was being restricted to v6.0 of the library instead of v8.2, which is the version the docs were written for. But when I looked in that version of the docs, there wasn't anything about error 1011 at all. And there's also seemingly no way to stop the ping from timing out (in this version of the library). So how can I stop the server from shutting itself down simply because nothing is connecting to it?